# Thunderbird shows no windows on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: email, thunderbird

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 on a Macbook Pro 17, Thunderbird has been updated to the latest release. I have the following problem:

Thunderbird shows only a short menu, but no windows at all. The window seem to be present though, because I can see it, if I click on the app icon and choose show windows.

I tried to delete `~/.thunderbird` and restart, but the main window of Thunderbird still does not show up.

I can choose <kbd>New Email</kbd> from the app menu, and the window shows, but the main window stays invisible.

How to fix that?

Comment: Try reinstalling Thunderbird.

Comment: Hey :-). Thank you for your answer, I tried to reinstall Thunderbird several times, no solution.

Comment: FYI, I had a problem with Thunderbird on 22.04 and 22.10 recently (different problem from you).  And I uninstalled it and then downloaded it from `https://www.thunderbird.net/` instead.  That worked for me...  If your problem persists, you might want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem, also with a 17" MacBook Pro (2010). After launch it looks like a window is about to draw to screen, then it disappears.

Thankfully I have found the solution:

Go to **Settings -> Screen Display**.
In **Display Mode** at the top, change it from **Join Displays** to **Single Display**, then click **Apply**.

The missing Thunderbird setup window should magically appear.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That was exactly the problem. Seem to be specific for Ubuntu on a. Macbook Pro 17".